# Obtener primer y ultimo dato laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

Buen día!

Tengo un problema necesito obtener el primer y ultimo dato de un campo asociado a una id a través de una consulta Eloquent.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código:

```php
public function fechasSesiones($request){ 
  
  return $fi = sesion::select('fecha')->orderBy('fecha','asc')->join('ficha_clinica','sesiones.ficha_id','=','ficha_clinica.id')->where('paciente_id','=',$request->paciente_id) ->first();
  return $ff = sesion::select('fecha')->orderBy('fecha','desc')->join('ficha_clinica','sesiones.ficha_id','=','ficha_clinica.id')->where('paciente_id','=',$request->paciente_id) ->first();
  return $sesion = $fi->push($ff)->toJson();
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrarnos el código PHP de eloquent que has intentado?

Comment: public function fechasSesiones($request){
        return $fi =sesion::select('fecha')
        ->orderBy('fecha','asc')
        ->join('ficha_clinica','sesiones.ficha_id','=','ficha_clinica.id')
        
    
        ->where('paciente_id','=',$request->paciente_id)
        ->first();
        return $ff=sesion::select('fecha')
        ->orderBy('fecha','desc')
        ->join('ficha_clinica','sesiones.ficha_id','=','ficha_clinica.id')
        
    
        ->where('paciente_id','=',$request->paciente_id)
        ->first();
        return $sesion=$fi->push($ff)->toJson();

Comment: Te vas a tardar mas en indagar eloquent que hacerlo con SQL puro (raw): `SELECT min(fecha) fechaMin, max(fecha) fechaMax FROM sesiones s INNER JOIN ficha_clinica fc ON fc.id = s.ficha_id WHERE paciente_id = $paciente_id`.

Comment: @IP13, no uses los comentarios para compartir información de tu pregunta. Pulsa [edit] y agrega la informanción en la pregunta. PD: no podes hacer 3 `return`; en el primero se corta la ejecución y el resto es código muerto.

Answer (score 0):

No creo que haya una solución que te traiga ambos en una sola llamada.

Seguramente esta es la mejor manera de obtenerlos:

Para conseguir el primero: `NombreModelo::orderBy('id', 'asc')->first();`

Para conseguir el último: `NombreModelo::orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();`

Comment: Entiendo , pero como podría unir ambas consultas? hay alguna forma que me retorne ambas fechas juntas?

Comment: Se podria lograr mediante una consulta SQL combinando MIN y MAX pero desconozco como utilizar la sintaxis eloquent para ello. 
Con lenguaje SQL seria algo así:
`SELECT MIN(fecha) as Minimo, MAX(fecha) as Maximo FROM table_name 
WHERE paciente_id = $request->paciente_id`

Comment: Tal como comenta Farid , no creo que haya una forma de hacerlo directamente en Laravel sin una consulta SQL

Answer (score 0):

Podes resolverlo facilmente, te doy un ejemplo sencillo y generico

```
$ventas = Venta:::orderBy('fecha', 'asc');

//primer valor    
$desde = $ventas->first();

//primer valor    
$hasta = $ventas->orderBy('fecha', 'desc')->first();

return response()->json(["desde"=>$desde,"hasta"=>$hasta],200);
```

De esta forma hacer una sola consulta y trabajas con los datos que ya tenes